# How to exclude certain plugins from war in grails 1.3.5

Tags: grails, packaging, config, war, grails-plugin

I'm seeking how to exclude plugins for specific environments. According to GRAILS documentation, starting with 1.3.5 it's now possible to disable a bunch of plugins. For example, I add the jetty plugin for local testing, but don't need it for deployment. I try to use the following in Config.groovy:

```
envname {
        . . .
        plugin {
            excludes = [ 'tomcat', 'jetty' ]
        }
}
```

But still, there's jetty jars in war file.
I tred also

```
    plugin.excludes = [ 'tomcat', 'jetty' ]
```

This doesn't work as well:

```
plugin.excludes = 'tomcat, jetty'
```

But also without any luck. Does anybody has a working example? Thanks!
P.S. Of course, war is being packaged with:

grails -Dgrails.env=envname war

Comment: I can delete the jars from the .war by using:

    grails.war.resources = { stagingDir, args ->
        delete {
            fileset(dir: "${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/lib", includes: "jetty-*.jar")
        }
    }

But can't find the way to not exclude them from the specified environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think disabling and excluding aren't the same thing.  In any event, I couldn't find a reference to what you are saying is possible in 1.3.5.  It isn't in the release notes.  I did see this in the 1.1 release notes if you look under Plugin Scopes:

http://grails.org/1.1+Release+Notes

Do you have a link to the 1.3.5 specific info about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi Gregg! 
According to http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.7.10 Plugin Dependencies, one can disable certain plugins

According to the issue 6653 http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-6653 , latter syntax should work (bug was fixed in 1.3.5).

Thanks for your suggestion about disabling a plugin in certain scope, but as far as I understand, this method requires plugin recompilation.

I just wandering, maybe it's possible to completely exclude the plugins from the WAR via hook etc.

Comment: Also edited the question text to always state that I need not to just disable but completely exclude the plugin for specified environment, thank you for suggestion.